# Installation of MARS (mips simulator) on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mips, ubuntu-11.04

I have downloaded the compressed MARS file and installed Java SDK.However,I'm not able to run MARS.Could someone guide me through the process?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more details?

Comment: After downloading the necessary files from http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/,I don't know how to actually install Mars.Double clicking on the .jar file just opens the folder.

Comment: Have you tried starting it from a terminal instead? `java -jar TheJarFile.jar`

Comment: Apparently my java installation hadn't gone right.It works now!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623707/how-to-install-mars-mips-on-ubuntu-14-04) solution:

You have to go to the MARS file directory to run the bash command.